# My project disappeared when I renamed it in git

Tags: xcode, git

I was putting the finishing touches on a project. One of those "finishing touches" was renaming the project. Now it's "gone". . I looked on GitHub and it's still "there", but I'm in over my head in terms of how to get my `master` and my renamed branch to interact properly. Here's how I got to this dreadful state:

I followed Apple's [How to Rename a Project](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-project_editor/RenamingaProject/RenamingaProject.html) post:

In git, from the command line, I checked out a branch to rename the project as follows:

```
git checkout -b rename-project
```

When I was done, I typed:

```
git add .
git commit -m "Renamed my project"
```

Then, I went back to the master to merge the 'rename-project` branch as follows:

```
git checkout master
```

> Project /Users/me/Documents/Developer/My Renamed Project.xcodeproj cannot be opened because it is missing its project.pbxproj file.

How do I get my 2 weeks' work back?

Comment: Hello there... Judging from your rep you should know your way around SO at least a little. I have removed the "Post Mortem" section of your question since it's... well not part of the question. Additionally I reformulated the queston you ask a little to ... quieten the tone a little. If you disagree, feel free to roll back or drop by in [chat] where you can find me in the Java room (139)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`master` doesn't have your renamed project yet. Close XCode, then do

```
git merge rename-project
```

and if that succeeds, you can reopen XCode.

Comment: You have no idea how much I appreciate this. I panicked when I got the warning and didn't even to attempt to merge it. It make perfect sense in hindsight, but all I could see was 2 weeks of work up in smoke. Thank you again!

Comment: No problem. By the way, `git` has some very nice safety nets (`git reflog`). If you commit something to `git`, it is almost always recoverable in case you screw up (unless you e.g. delete the `.git` folder).